# Вывести словарь, отсортировав по ключу и значению

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, словари

Выполняю задание на степике: https://stepik.org/lesson/296967/step/7?unit=278695
(программа на вход принимает строки, в которых указывается имя таксиста, а через запятую его заказ. Ввод прекращается на строке 'конец'. Нужно вывести имя таксиста и его среднюю оценку в порядке убывания, если у кого-то есть еще такая средняя оценка, вывести имена таксистов по алфавиту в порядке убывания)

Вот мой код:

```
data = {}
while True:
    i = input()

    if i == 'конец':
        break

    if i[:i.find(',')] in data:
        data[i[:i.find(',')]][0] += int(i[i.find(',') + 2:])
        data[i[:i.find(',')]][1] += 1

    if i[:i.find(',')] not in data:
        data[i[:i.find(',')]] = [int(i[i.find(',') + 2:]), 1]

for key, value in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda name: name[1], reverse=True):
    print(key, value[0] / value[1])
```

На первом тесте у меня все нормально работает, но когда я отправляю свой тестовый словарь в сортировку, например: {"Авраам": 2.5, "Джек": 4.0, "Гермиона": 4.0}, прилетает:

```
Джек 4.0
Гермиона 4.0
Авраам 2.5
```

А должно:

```
Гермиона 4.0
Джек 4.0
Авраам 2.5
```

Как мне отсортировать все по условию? Пробовал создать новый список и там что-то отсортировать, но это слишком громоздко и некрасиво, уверен, что есть хороший и лаконичный способ это сделать, но я его не знаю в силу не самого большого опыта

Comment: Вы понимаете, что не сортируете словарь, а выводите словарь на печать в отсортированном виде?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
arr = {
    'Джек': 4.0,
    'Гермиона': 4.0,
    'Авраам': 2.5,
}

res = sorted(arr.items(), key=lambda obj: (-obj[1], obj[0]))

print(*res, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему просто поставив знак минус перед аргументом:

```
for key, value in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])):
```

Решение @Zhihar тоже отличное :)

Comment: решение Zhihar прежде всего - правильное, т.к. в вашем коде была сортировка только по значению, а уже потОм - отличное ;)